# How to center text between two rectangles in TiKZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I have the following TiKZ code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \newcommand{\delim}[1]{\draw(#1,-0.2) -- (#1,-0.5);}

  \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);

  \draw (1,0) rectangle (2,1);

  \delim{0}
  \delim{2}

  \node[below] at(0,0){\small Unused};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This results in this image:

[image]

But I'd like to center the text between the two boxes, sort of like this image:

[image]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

The text is centered under `(0,0)` which is the coordinate you provided. I think you want to use `(1,0)`:

```
\node[below] at(1,0) {\small Unused};
```

If you want thicker lines, you  use `[thick]`, `[ultra thick]` options, or specify an line width as `[line width=2pt]` :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand{\delim}[1]{\draw [thick] (#1,-0.2) -- (#1,-0.5);}

  \draw [ultra thick] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
  \draw [ultra thick] (1,0) rectangle (2,1);

  \delim{0}
  \delim{2}

  \node[below] at(1,0){\small Unused};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Another method is to modify the `\delim` macro to take a second parameter and use that to label the center of the line segments, `A` and `B` in the example below. Then you can compute the midpoint of the two points using `($(A)!0.5!(B)$)` and place the text at that position. This solution has the added benefit that if you change the coordinates in the `\delim` macro, the text will be centered between the two points.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand{\delim}[2]{\draw [thick] (#1,-0.2) -- (#1,-0.5); \node (#2) at (#1,-0.35) {};}

  \draw [ultra thick] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
  \draw [ultra thick] (1,0) rectangle (2,1);

  \delim{0}{A}% Label this as (A)
  \delim{2}{B}% Label this as (B)

  \node at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$) {\small Unused};% Place the node midway between (A) and (B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that this requires `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` in the preamble.